# python selenium: element click intercepted:

Tags: python, selenium, element

I'm trying to click via find_element_by_xpath() as i did it always. In the case below, there is an error when try to click this element. I'm quite new with selenium and researched already. It seems that i have to click on specific coordination. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? i'm struggling for quite a while.

section of HTML code:

```
<map ng-if="!enableSvgHighlighting" id="clickareasVillage" name="clickareasVillage" 
ng-show="areas.village.length > 0" class="">

     <area ng-repeat="a in areas.village" location-id="32" on-pointer-over="highlightStart(32)" on-
     pointer-out="highlightStop(32)" clickable="openBuildingDialog(32)" tg-
     coords="758,341,758,342,761,343,763,344,767,345,769" 
     coords="758,341,758,342,761,343,763,344,767,345,769" 
     shape="poly" building-positioner="32" class="clickable">
```

my Code:

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//map[@id='clickareasVillage']/area[2]")))
       
ele1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//map[@id='clickareasVillage']/area[2]")
ele1.click()
```

error message:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element 
<area ng-repeat="a in areas.village" location-id="32" 
on-pointer-over="highlightStart(32)" on-pointer-out="highlightStop(32)" clickable="openBuildingDialog(32)" 
tg-coords="758,341,758,342,761,343,763,344,767,345,769" coords="758,341,758,342,761,343,763,344,767,345,769" 
shape="poly" building-positioner="32" 
class="clickable"> is not clickable at point (391, 477). 
Other element would receive the click: <img ng-if="!enableSvgHighlighting" 
ng-show="areas.village.length > 0" class="clickareas" src="layout/images/x.gif" usemap="#clickareasVillage" data-cmp-info="9">
```

on other treads at stackoverflow, people suggest to use the following line. If i try, there is a TimeoutExeption.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//map[@id='clickareasVillage']/area[2]")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said above, usually when you encounter this error it's because a pop-up or an invisible overlay is preventing the driver from clicking on your element.

You said that JS clicking wasn't working either so i'm going to give you 2 quick workarounds that you can try:

1. ActionChains to move and click on your element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

2. Send keys using ActionChains

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

for i in range(#determine how much time):
    ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.TAB).perform() #tab until element is selected
ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform() #press enter to "click" on it
```

Let me know if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//map[@id='clickareasVillage']/area[2]")))
        
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be something which could be preventing click on the element, check if any pop-up occuring.